# Recycle USB port in C++

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I need to simulate plug/unplug for USB device in C++ under Windows environment. I know the existence of this IOCTL

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537243(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

(IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT) which indeed is what I am looking for, but I don't know how to use.
Is there anyone which can tell me who I can find an example or share some lines of code in order to help me, please!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "kernel-mode I/O control request". Not going to happen from a regular C++ program. It's the correct request, but it's issued from within the (USB) driver stack itself.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in User Mode land and using C++ I'd recommend looking at the [devcon sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Out of the box you can use it on the command line to issue PnP or disable/enable requests to devices. The [source code is also available](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/DevCon-Sample-4e95d71c), so you can use that as a start to get this functionality added to your environment.